Pull light insert works on one fixture but not other
I have a couple live light fixtures so I bought pull chain inserts ; one works with the insert but other doesn’t!  I then tried just bulb in the fixture and it works but not with the insert? So I tried insert in a different fixture and works, so why doesn’t it work in that one fixture?

The center contact in the fixture probably isn't making contact with the contact in the insert.  With the power off, breaker off, pry the center contact up a bit.
